# Should [file.exists] return true?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across the tag [file.exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file.exists) while reviewing [a Ruby question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156516/file-exist-wont-find-file-that-exists). In Ruby, there is are two related methods, yet the question asks about the latter.

- `File::exists?` - now deprecated
- `File::exist?`

At the moment, there are [57 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file.exists) with this tag.

- [1 question does not tag a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511664/file-exists-returns-false-in-unittest-context)
- 0 followers
- [Top question has 118 votes, 37 stars, 87K views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216753/check-existence-of-directory-and-create-if-doesnt-exist)
- Such method (or a variant) is common across Ruby, Java/Android, C#, R, DotNet
- [29.8% of questions with this tag have been unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/file.exists/topusers)

Based on the burninate request rules:

1. Cannot be the only tag for a question, since it is not language-specific. (Again, [the 1 question without a specified language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511664/file-exists-returns-false-in-unittest-context))
2. On topic (skip)
3. Provides meaningful information to the post, but it *could maybe* be merged with [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file), since most questions already include the method in the title.
4. Does convey the same meaning across all questions -- OP has an issue when checking whether a file exists.

Once burninated, I think the 57 questions should be tagged with [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file)
, if anything else at all. Most of them have 1+ language-based tags that are popular enough, increasing views.

**EDIT** - Another option is to merge with [file-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-exists):

- [Does not have an empty tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/file-exists/info)
- [350 questions, with 22.3% unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/file-exists/topusers)
- [Top question has 38 votes, 10 stars, 36K views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596447/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-server-using-its-url)
- [1 question uses both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094861/vba-check-if-file-exists-in-a-computer-in-domain)

Comment: Ah, a burnination proposal. Set all phrases to pun! (Sorry, I just had to wait for such an occasion.)

Comment: Also [\[file-exists\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-exists).

Comment: The question without a language is C#-related (note the `.cs` file, and the solution involving a specific Visual Studio project setting)

Comment: @approxiblue feel free to edit my proposal to include that. I was not aware of that tag until now. IDK whether file.exists should be merged into it, or both just thrown away.

Comment: @PaulRoub, yes, but it is not tagged with a language making it harder to appear in search results, etc etc.

Comment: @HunterStevens Right. But tags are editable, and I was pointing out which tag would be appropriate if that was desired.

Comment: @PaulRoub I completely understand. I was just trying to provide as many stats as I could for this proposal, and #1 of the criteria worked well with such question.

Comment: @HunterStevens I've tagged the only question with C# (as both Q&A seem to use C# for language). Overall I'd vote to merge file.exists to file-exists (either retagging or synonym).

Comment: The 57 questions link is broken.

Comment: "29.8% of questions with this tag have been **UN**answered" not "Only 29.8% of questions with this tag have been answered"

Comment: @HappyCoder I misread the stat. Will remove it.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm that could be because of the new nav system... I am replacing the link with one the tag directs to.

Comment: @Jongware: Was [that SciFi Guy](http://www.thatscifiguy.com/?p=947) your inspiration?

Comment: @approxiblue [tag:file-exists] should go. That's a horrible tag.

Comment: Anyone know how long it takes for a proposal such as this to be reviewed? I know it has only been a few days, but there are no answers yet for it even.

Comment: With 28 upvotes and only 1 down, you can pretty safely assume that your proposal has widespread agreement. It's time to start cleaning up questions. My gut tells me that this should generally be left to people with edit privileges, but I'm not sure if that's recorded anywhere.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'd rather not perform a bunch of edits until I get the OK from a mod or something.

Comment: You don't get any kind of official statement. That's not the way burninate works. It's all community handled.